# Property 'entries' does not exist on type - Typescript noje.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use .entries() in Typescript, but it gives me error:

```
Property 'entries' does not exist on type
```

I have es2017 in lib also tried, to change target to es2017 or esnext, but it doesn't fix it. I am using Vscode and node - v14.17.1

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: How/where are you using ".entries"?

Comment: @ArielAlvarado I am trying to use .entries() on an object. const obj = { name: 'a' }

Answer (score 0):

You should use entries with the **Object** class. Example:

```
const obj={
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
Object.entries(obj);
```

[Check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)